# How to go one path backward and store the path in variable

Tags: bash, shell-script

Suppose I am already storing a path in a variable as:

```
tmp=/home/abc/xyz
```

So what I want now is to go one way backward and store it in a variable as

```
tmp2=/home/abc
```

Please let me know how to achieve that without any error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In zsh, `tmp3=$tmp:h` same as in csh, vim, etc except it works better for values of `$tmp` like `dir` (for which it gives `.` while csh gives `dir`) or `foo/bar/` (for which it gives `foo` while csh gives `foo/bar`). For `dir=..` or `dir=.`, it gives `.`, like `dirname` does.

Comment: `tmp2="${tmp%/*}"`?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a job for `dirname`. The files/directories don't have to exist, it just cuts off the last part, so you'll never get an error. For `/` it returns `/`.

```
tmp2="$(dirname -- "$tmp")"
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to `dirname`. This requires path is not empty and not a relative path.

```
tmp2=$(set -f; IFS=/; set -- $tmp; echo "/${*:1:$# ? $# - 1: 0}")
```

Either way I'm not a fan of their use of subshell. So a function version of `dirname` that assigns result to a global variable like `__` will be better but it's going to be a lot more verbose.